# Smart contract architecture

Tags: erc-20, architecture

I want to write the smart contract architecture for a new smart contract on Ethereum ERC20, how can I do that, and what does it mean smart contract architecture.

Comment: Hi there. If you don't know what it means, how do you know you want to do it? :-) If someone has told you to do this, then you need to clarify with them what the exact requirements for the "architecture" are. Is it a set of smart contracts that together perform some function relating to ERC-20, or a new architecture to run contracts (e.g. a new EVM)?  Or is it just simply an ERC-20 contract, and someone has thrown the work "architecture" in there?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thank you for your answer, it'll be a smart contract with some modification and it shouldn't be grammatical it should be simple, I want to learn the way of doing it therefore I'm asking about any tips can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

- Figure out and write down the main task. What exactly do you need this contract to do?
- What information will it be working with? Figure out data structure that you're gonna use, how many variables you're gonna need and what types will they be.
- Assess this structure gaswise (storage costs a lot). Which of the variables have to be in storage and which are not necessarily?
- Figure out what functionality overall you will need for the contract and lay out a plan on how to better and more efficiently distribute this functionality between different modules (functions in your case).
- Assess these operations gaswise.
- For every state change you will need an event. What will they be called? Which parameters will they have for you to better track changes after deployment?

That should be a start. After you make this first draft you will understand the process better and would want to improve on it. Talk to your manager about the implementation, listen to all of the suggestions and thoughts from a person who will be implementing it. That might bring some changes and will give you a better understanding on how to do it in the future.

Comment: thank you so much @Whhytecrowe, could you give me a real example to be sure I got your explanation 100%

Comment: @crypto have you ever worked with smart contracts before or have you programmed before?

Comment: I'm a developer yes but didn't develop smart-contract before

Comment: @crypto I would recommend reading on the structure of Solidity contracts, gas system and storage.olidity

Comment: @Whyytecrowe could I have your telegram account or any way of communication.